# Spring Boot @Async annotation and MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, resttemplate

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.6 and Java 10. I did the following service that only hits an external rest api using RestTemplate.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class DbApiClientImpl implements DbApiClient {

  private final String URL_DELIMITER = "/";
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  private String url;

  public DbApiClientImpl(
      RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate,
      @Value("${dbapi.namespace}") String namespace,
      @Value("${dbapi.url}") String uri,
      @Value("${dbapi.username}") String username,
      @Value("${dbapi.password}") String password) {

  this.restTemplate = restTemplate.basicAuthorization(username, 
                      password).build();
  this.url = namespace.concat(uri);
}

   @Override
   @Async("asyncExecutor")
   public Merchant fetchMerchant(String id) {
       ResponseEntity<Merchant> response = 
        restTemplate.getForEntity(url.concat(URL_DELIMITER).concat(id), 
        Merchant.class);
   return response.getBody();
   }
}
```

And the following test using MockeRestServiceServer:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(value = {DbApiClient.class})
public class DbApiClientTest {

   private static final String TEST_NAME = "test";
   private static final String TEST_NAME_BAD_REQUEST = "test- 
   1";
   private static final String TEST_NAME_SERVER_ERROR = 
  "test-2";

   @Autowired DbApiClient dbApiClient;

   @Value("${dbapi.namespace}")
   private String namespace;

   @Value("${dbapi.url}")
   private String dbApiUrl;

   @Autowired private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

   @Autowired private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   @Test
   public void test() throws 
   JsonProcessingException, IOException {
      Merchant mockMerchantSpec = populateFakeMerchant();
      String jsonResponse = 
          objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mockMerchantSpec);
      mockServer
         .expect(manyTimes(), 
           requestTo(dbApiUrl.concat("/").concat(TEST_NAME)))
         .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
         .andRespond(withSuccess(jsonResponse, 
                       MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

       assertNotNull(dbApiClient.fetchMerchant(TEST_NAME));
  }
```

The thing is that I'm getting the following exception when I run the test "No further request expected HTTP GET http://localthost... excecuted"

So seems that the @Async is borking MockerServerService response...
Also, If I commented the @Async annotation everything works just fine and I get all test green.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Update:

As per @M.Deinum's comment. I removed the CompletableFuture from the service but I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: Remove the `CompletableFuture` from your method, that doesn't add anything. Or make your method return `Future<Merchant>` instead of what you have now. That way your calling code will wait for the response. Currently it won't wait and the test will finish (as the thread runs in the background).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum same exception.. :(

Comment: I actually doubt this will work. You are returning a result from an async method. It should return either `void` or a `Future` so your calling code knows what to expect. So my guess is your code is wrong and not your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code and not your test.

If you read the documentation ([the JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionInterceptor.html)) of `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` you will see the mention that only `void` or `Future` is supported as a return type. You are returning a plain object and that is internally treated as `void`.

A call to that method will always respond with `null`. As your test is running very quickly everything has been teared down already (or is in the process of being teared down) no more calls are expected to be made.

To fix, fix your method signature and return a `Future<Merchant>` so that you can block and wait for the result.

```
@Override
@Async("asyncExecutor")
public Future<Merchant> fetchMerchant(String id) {
   ResponseEntity<Merchant> response = 
    restTemplate.getForEntity(url.concat(URL_DELIMITER).concat(id), 
    Merchant.class);
   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response.getBody());
}
```

Now your calling code knows about the returned `Future` as well as the Spring Async code. Now in your test you can now call `get` on the returned value (maybe with a timeout to receive an error if something fails). TO inspect the result.

Comment: This is correct buddy! Thanks for your comments! :)